# SageMath notebook is not opening

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, sage

I'm trying to open the Sage's notebook, but it isn't working.

I have no idea where this error came from, because the notebook was working this week. I guess it just popped up out of nowhere.

The message's error is:

```
    sage: notebook()
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
EnvironmentError                          Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-3728cb3d7c7d> in <module>()
----> 1 notebook()

/home/jerome/opt/SageMath/src/sage/misc/lazy_import.pyx in sage.misc.lazy_import.LazyImport.__call__ (/home/jerome/opt/SageMath/src/build/cythonized/sage/misc/lazy_import.c:3634)()
    384             True
    385         """
--> 386         return self._get_object()(*args, **kwds)
    387 
    388     def __repr__(self):

/home/jerome/opt/SageMath/src/sage/misc/lazy_import.pyx in sage.misc.lazy_import.LazyImport._get_object (/home/jerome/opt/SageMath/src/build/cythonized/sage/misc/lazy_import.c:2241)()
    244         elif self._at_startup and not startup_guard:
    245             print('Option ``at_startup=True`` for lazy import {0} not needed anymore'.format(self._name))
--> 246         self._object = getattr(__import__(self._module, {}, {}, [self._name]), self._name)
    247         alias = self._as_name or self._name
    248         if self._deprecation is not None:

/home/jerome/opt/SageMath/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sagenb/notebook/notebook_object.py in <module>()
     15 import time, os, shutil, signal, tempfile
     16 
---> 17 import notebook as _notebook
     18 
     19 import run_notebook

/home/jerome/opt/SageMath/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sagenb/notebook/notebook.py in <module>()
     33 
     34 # Sage libraries
---> 35 from sagenb.misc.misc import (pad_zeros, cputime, tmp_dir, load, save,
     36                               ignore_nonexistent_files, unicode_str)
     37 

/home/jerome/opt/SageMath/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sagenb/misc/misc.py in <module>()
    379 
    380 try:
--> 381     from sage.misc.cython import cython
    382 except ImportError:
    383     @stub

/home/jerome/opt/SageMath/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sage/misc/cython.py in <module>()
     28 
     29 # CBLAS can be one of multiple implementations
---> 30 cblas_pc = pkgconfig.parse('cblas')
     31 cblas_libs = list(cblas_pc['libraries'])
     32 cblas_library_dirs = list(cblas_pc['library_dirs'])

/home/jerome/opt/SageMath/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkgconfig-1.1.0-py2.7.egg/pkgconfig/pkgconfig.py in parse(packages)
    185 
    186     for package in packages.split():
--> 187         for k, v in parse_package(package).items():
    188             result[k].update(v)
    189 

/home/jerome/opt/SageMath/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkgconfig-1.1.0-py2.7.egg/pkgconfig/pkgconfig.py in parse_package(package)
    158 
    159         # Execute the query to pkg-config and clean the result.
--> 160         out = _query(package, '--cflags --libs')
    161         out = out.replace('\\"', '')
    162 

/home/jerome/opt/SageMath/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkgconfig-1.1.0-py2.7.egg/pkgconfig/pkgconfig.py in _wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
     56             return func(*args, **kwargs)
     57         except OSError:
---> 58             raise EnvironmentError("pkg-config is not installed")
     59 
     60     return _wrapper

EnvironmentError: pkg-config is not installed
```

If you guys can help me, I'll be very thankful!

Comment: I think we need more information - what version of Sage, what operating system, did you try to upgrade recently, did you download a binary or compile from source ...

Comment: (Also, recompiling from source should fix any problems, but of course that may not be an option depending upon your setup and/or permissions.)